Is there an equivalent of caniuse for commands on posix systems?
I'm thinking about using a callout to the jq command in a utility script I'm writing, rather than parsing JSON manually.
In order to make the script as portable as possible, I want to know which flavors of Unix/Linux/MacOS/WSL/etc support this command without any additional package installation.
Likewise, in the past, I've found that some scripts use call-outs to wget, which is missing in at least one flavor by default.
That got me thinking: Is there any sort of tool that tells people whether it's "safe" in this way to use an arbitrary command in their scripts? Ideally, it would act like the caniuse site by showing which major flavors do and don't support a command in their default shells.
===
EDIT: With thanks to user Kusalananda for pointing out that my examples aren't POSIX commands, I changed the title to avoid mislabeling them as such.

What's wrong with having a dependency on one or two external utilities? It's common for software to have and document dependencies. I'd would suggest doing that any day over trying to do your own JSON parsing in bash.  Also, neither jq nor wget are POSIX commands.

There are a few tools or sites which can be used to find out which version of a project is available in various distributions (including non-Linux systems); see Is there a tool/website to compare package status in different Linux distributions?
It’s much harder to categorically state which systems have a given package by default. In some cases there is no really reliable default; for example, most Debian systems will have wget when initially set up (because it’s “standard” there), but Debian container images don’t include it by default, and there’s nothing forcing wget to be installed on a Debian system.
There’s also no requirement for users to use their system’s package (if any) to provide a given binary. They may also have both a packaged version and a manually-installed version available, and looking at only the package may give a false impression (e.g. if you need at least a specific version, and the installed package is older, but the user has an appropriate version on their path).
All this means that you can’t do much better than check for a command’s existence and fail if you can’t find all the commands you need, with links to instructions explaining how to install them.

Great, detailed answer. I can't upvote yet because my account is new, but assuming I don't get a magical solution from somebody, I'll plan to mark it as the accepted answer soon.

Almost no command will be present by default on all flavors with no package installation.
You can consider the mandatory utilities section of POSIX standard, but while many of them are present on all systems (grep, basename, cut, grep, cmp...) others are not common at all or need separate packages (compress, pax, those dealing with SCSS files...).
There's no fault in using additional programs and requiring that they are available.
A generic script that required jq could begin with:
if ! command -v jq 2> /dev/null; then
  echo "You need to install jq to use this program"
  exit 69  # EX_UNAVAILABLE
fi

A rule of thumb I have sometimes used when writing general scripts (i.e. not ones where I already know the system and I could assume that certain programs are installed) is to consider that those packages that are considered Essential by Debian/Ubuntu will be there, and the rest may not.
Essential ones are a set of packages that "must be available and usable on the system at all times" (see Debian Policy Manual on Essential Packages).
Debian packages can use essential programs without declaring them. In all other cases they would have to declare the dependency. As such, if the program was being packaged into a .deb, those non-essential utils such as jq or wget that you test for are the same that would have to be declared in the package, while you could skip those in e.g. coreutils.
This list is obviously not universal, and there might be differences between several distros in the Debian-family (as well as newer releases including programs that were not essential in earlier versions) but I find it good enough. If it's in an essential package and in POSIX it is probably safe to use directly. If it's not an essential package, you know at least it will not be available there, so you should check.
Some caveats:

There are many Linux distros. Some are really slim and will provide next to nothing
WSL uses Ubuntu by default, but it could be using a different distribution
MacOS uses mostly userland binaries from FreeBSD. Often outdated.

More annoying than missing programs are those with different behavior / missing features you may want to use.
For example:

Mac OS comes with bash 3.2.57 (2007), in order to have a modern bash (and its features) it would need to be upgraded with homebrew (use BASH_VERSION if you need to check the bash version which is running your script)
The sed command has slightly different semantics on its -i parameter on Mac OS (which uses sed from FreeBSD) and most Linux (using GNU sed)
Sometimes the wget you find is actually a busybox applet (which lacks many features of the "normal" GNU wget)
Features may have been added on a recent version, and not on the version of the program distributed by certain older distros.
Similarly, you can expect that features described as a "GNU extensions" won't be available on OS not using the GNU version of that util.

Having dependencies is not bad (probably it's even the right choice), and you don't need to support every system. Specially when you won't have a test system on which to test it. You will need to draw a line somewhere, often there will be one or a few setups you support which are those you use and may test, and a best-effort and general expectation to support others.

"Sometimes the wget you find is actually a busybox applet" – Or, on PowerShell, curl is simply an alias for Invoke-WebRequest, whose parameters are in no way compatible with curl, so it only works for the most basic of cases.

I believe the curl alias was removed from ps

There is no such resource currently. I seriously wish there was, because it would make my job much simpler. Package availability is solved (see https://repology.org/ for the currently best resource for that), but not what gets installed by default. For a lot of Linux distributions this is actually not exceptionally difficult to check even without installing, it just takes work to chase the full dependency tree (for example, for Arch Linux, see the dependencies for the base package, though you need to follow dependencies for each thing it depends on). What gets tricky is that the ‘base’ for a given distro often varies based on the installation target (a lot of distros leave a number of things out in Docker images for example) and possibly the choice of user environment (you obviously get a different set of leaf dependencies if you choose to install a GUI).
Speaking as somebody who writes a lot of shell script for work though, there are some things you can do to help mitigate these kinds of issues:

Use command -v to look for commands. This works pretty much everywhere you are ever going to care about supporting, it can be trivially turned into an if condition (for example: command -v jq >/dev/null 2>&1) or used to assign a variable (for example: JQ_PATH="$(command -v jq 2>/dev/null || true)"), and it avoids the possibility of trying to invoke aliases defined by the user (which is almost never what you want to do in a portable script).
Python, while not universal in and of itself (Alpine Linux and FreeBSD are trivial examples of systems that do not ship Python by default), can often be used to work around ‘missing’ commands. Almost anything you can do with jq can also be done with Python’s json module and print(). Basic HTTP/HTTPS interaction can easily be done with Python’s urllib. readlink can be emulated pretty trivially using Python. And there are plenty of others. The one caveat is ensuring you handle version differences in Python itself sanely, but depending on your target platforms and what exactly you need to do that may not be an issue. Note that this is not a suggestion to write your scripts in Python, but to allow for using python -c to run short snippets of code instead of calling out to equivalent programs.
From an organizational standpoint, when more than one command might be used based on the system or other factors, put the logic for that in a function and call the function instead of putting it inline in your code. This will do wonders for helping to preserve your sanity, and also ensures that if you need to use a command more than once, it’s easy to do so.
Make an effort to decide on a policy for what platforms you actually support. This may be as simple as ‘if it’s EOL upstream, I will not support it’. Then put together test environments for the major platforms that fit your support policy (for Linux, testing on Alpine, Arch, Debian, Fedora, openSUSE, RHEL (or CentOS Stream) and Ubuntu will get you majority coverage of actual users, and indirect coverage of most users who aren’t using those distros (because almost everything other than NixOS and Gentoo that has decent market share is based on one of those seven distros)).
As long as you don’t care about commercial UNIX platforms like AIX and Solaris, about 95% of the differences you see in behavior of common commands will be a split across some subset of GNU, BSD, POSIX, Busybox, and macOS. Busybox will usually be the problem child because it lacks a lot of things that are available in all four of the other ‘flavors’, and has irritatingly different semantics in a number of cases. It’s increasingly important to support it though because of Alpine Linux using it by default (but you should not assume if you are running on Alpine that you’re using Busybox, installing the ‘regular’ version of a command will override the Busybox one there).
For Linux specifically, you may need to differentiate distros to figure out paths to specific things. The canonical way to do this is to look at the os-release file, which can be sourced directly in any Bourne shell derivative (including bash and POSIX sh). Some non-Linux platforms are also starting to ship files with the same fields customized for their platform, so it may be usable elsewhere as well (though outside of Linux, uname is usually good enough).

